# Equal in MySQL does not return rows, replace nothing with nothing in where clause does

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

Short Summary: Running in a Drupal environment, I have a query, which returns an empty result set, unless I run some kind of command on the result of an inner select. This can be Trim, replace, upper.

All the unneeded fields have been removed from the select, so I only have the relevant part of the query left.

```
mysql> SELECT HEX(taxonomy_term_field_data_node_field_data.name)  
   FROM node_field_data 
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT td.*, tn.nid AS nid 
              FROM taxonomy_term_field_data td
              LEFT JOIN taxonomy_index tn ON tn.tid = td.tid
              WHERE (td.vid IN ('category'))
             ) taxonomy_term_field_data_node_field_data
   ON node_field_data.nid = taxonomy_term_field_data_node_field_data.nid  
   WHERE (taxonomy_term_field_data_node_field_data.name = "Politik");
Empty set (0.01 sec)
```

It is possible to select from the `taxonomy_term_field_data` table when it is not in the join (where name = "Politik")?

```
mysql> SELECT name FROM taxonomy_term_field_data WHERE name = "Politik"; 
+---------+
| name    |
+---------+
| Politik |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And If I replace nothing with nothing in the query, I get results back:
This also work with UPPER on both strings or TRIM.

```
mysql> SELECT HEX(taxonomy_term_field_data_node_field_data.name) 
       FROM node_field_data 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT td.*, tn.nid AS nid
                  FROM taxonomy_term_field_data td
                  LEFT JOIN taxonomy_index tn ON tn.tid = td.tid 
                  WHERE (td.vid IN  ('category'))
                 ) taxonomy_term_field_data_node_field_data
       ON node_field_data.nid = taxonomy_term_field_data_node_field_data.nid  
       WHERE (REPLACE(taxonomy_term_field_data_node_field_data.name, "", "") = "Politik");
+----------------------------------------------------+
| HEX(taxonomy_term_field_data_node_field_data.name) |
+----------------------------------------------------+
| 506F6C6974696B                                     |
| 506F6C6974696B                                     |
| 506F6C6974696B                                     |
+----------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

I have also tried and do an update name = trim(name) in the `taxonomy_term_field_data table`, but that does not work.

One of the queries are using the where and the other a conditional index, but any input on how to fix this is very welcomed.

```
mysql> explain SELECT taxonomy_term_field_data_node_field_data.name  FROM node_field_data LEFT JOIN (SELECT td.*, tn.nid AS nid             FROM taxonomy_term_field_data td             LEFT JOIN taxonomy_index tn ON tn.tid = td.tid             WHERE (td.vid IN  ('category'))            ) taxonomy_term_field_data_node_field_data          ON node_field_data.nid = taxonomy_term_field_data_node_field_data.nid  WHERE (trim(taxonomy_term_field_data_node_field_data.name) = "Politik");
+----+-------------+-----------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+--------------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table           | type  | possible_keys                                | key         | key_len | ref                      | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+--------------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | node_field_data | index | PRIMARY,node__id__default_langcode__langcode | node__vid   | 4       | NULL                     |   20 | Using index |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>      | ref   | <auto_key0>                                  | <auto_key0> | 5       | v15x.node_field_data.nid |   14 | Using where |
|  2 | DERIVED     | td              | ALL   | taxonomy_term__tree,taxonomy_term__vid_name  | NULL        | NULL    | NULL                     | 1404 | Using where |
|  2 | DERIVED     | tn              | ref   | term_node                                    | term_node   | 4       | v15x.td.tid              |    1 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-----------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+--------------------------+------+-------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain SELECT taxonomy_term_field_data_node_field_data.name  FROM node_field_data LEFT JOIN (SELECT td.*, tn.nid AS nid             FROM taxonomy_term_field_data td             LEFT JOIN taxonomy_index tn ON tn.tid = td.tid             WHERE (td.vid IN  ('category'))            ) taxonomy_term_field_data_node_field_data          ON node_field_data.nid = taxonomy_term_field_data_node_field_data.nid  WHERE (taxonomy_term_field_data_node_field_data.name = "Politik");
+----+-------------+-----------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+--------------------------+------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table           | type  | possible_keys                                | key         | key_len | ref                      | rows | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+-----------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+--------------------------+------+-----------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | node_field_data | index | PRIMARY,node__id__default_langcode__langcode | node__vid   | 4       | NULL                     |   20 | Using index           |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>      | ref   | <auto_key1>                                  | <auto_key1> | 5       | v15x.node_field_data.nid |   14 | Using index condition |
|  2 | DERIVED     | td              | ALL   | taxonomy_term__tree,taxonomy_term__vid_name  | NULL        | NULL    | NULL                     | 1404 | Using where           |
|  2 | DERIVED     | tn              | ref   | term_node                                    | term_node   | 4       | v15x.td.tid              |    1 | Using index           |
+----+-------------+-----------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+--------------------------+------+-----------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: After more investigation, it seems to be related to the AWS aurora database, since it does not happen on a standard MySQL database.  
They are looking into it, but any input on possible solutions are still very welcome.

Comment: Can you turn off index condition pushdown with the [optimizer_switch](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/switchable-optimizations.html) in Aurora?  This looks like a bug that may have made it across from MySQL 5.6 into Aurora.

Comment: Thank you - I have just tested it and it will return results.
For anybody who needs it, adding this to the connection array in settings.php will disable the index pushdown optimization in Drupal:

    'pdo' => array(
          \PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET @@SESSION.optimizer_switch="index_condition_pushdown=off";',
    ),